# Chilling during restart of Spacex first stage engine

Tags: spacex, recovery, restartable-engine, chilling

As I know that all the liquid rocket engines go through chilling process for different components (like pipes, engine, injector plate, etc.) before starting the ignition. At the time of launch the chilling is done with liquid nitrogen and then the ignition happens.

But then the real question arises, Is [SpaceX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_reusable_launch_system_development_program) doing chilling before restarting the engine for booster recovery? If yes, how are they doing chilling for different components while recovery of the first stage?